# How to automate backups in mysqldump from one server to an external disk

Tags: mysql

I need your help in configuring mysqldump in order to automatically download backups from one server to an external disk in a fixed time (Everyday at 6:00 Pm). If mysqldump is unable to do that, can your suggest another software?

Comment: What operating system are you using and how are your external disks attached?

Comment: Could you specify your Operating System, first guess would be to setup a `cronjob` on unix/linux or a `scheduled task` on windows

Comment: I'm using Windows server 2008

Comment: Answer updated to include output path specification.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your operating system's scheduler to automatically run the `mysqldump` command at your desired times, e.g. `cron` on Linux and the Task Scheduler on Windows.

To have `mysqldump` write to the external disk, you can mount the disk so the destination path is reachable to `mysqldump` and use it in the output path. To specify the output path, you can either use `>` redirection or the `--result-file` option.

Both approaches work on Linux/Unix but this distinction is important for Windows where redirection won't work properly using PowerShell. This is because redirection on PowerShell produces `UTF-16` using redirection which cannot be read. The `--result-file` option will provide `ASCII` output that can be read.

**Windows Examples**

```
C:\> mysqldump.exe –e –u[username] -p[password] -h[hostname] [dbname] > [C:\path\to\mybackup.sql]
C:\> mysqldump.exe –e –u[username] -p[password] -h[hostname] [dbname] --result-file [C:\path\to\mybackup.sql]
```

**Linux/Unix Examples**

```
# mysqldump -u[username] -p[password] -h[hostname] [dbname] > [/path/to/mybackup.sql]
# mysqldump -u[username] -p[password] -h[hostname] [dbname] --result-file [/path/to/mybackup.sql]
```

More information is available here:

- Complete: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html
- Quick: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/

Depending on your backup requirements, you may also want to consider other options such as [Percona XtraBackup](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup), LVM snapshots (e.g. [mylvmbackup](http://www.lenzg.net/mylvmbackup/)), etc. This [Percona XtraBackup presentation](https://www.percona.com/files/percona-live/Vadim_Percona-Live-Xtrabackup.pdf) has a comparison table on slide 3.

Comment: Thx! Is there any place to specifiy the output path in mysqldumper?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include options for and examples of specifying the output path.

Comment: Thx Grokify for your help. Let me try if it works! I was wondering if the automatic backups are possible in mysqldumper software. If yes, How?